# Column entries of a matrix sum to zero, so what are the properties?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, determinant

What kind of properties does a matrix whose column entries sum to zero have?

$$ \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{m1} & \cdots & a_{mn} \end{pmatrix}$$

Where $a_{11}+\cdots+a_{m1}=0$ and so on.

Answer (score 7):

You have
$$a_{mk} = - \sum_{j=1}^{m-1} a_{jk}$$ for all $k$. This means the last row vector is a linear combination of the remaining row vectors. Hence, the rank of the matrix is at most $\min(m,n)-1$.

Comment: What!? How do you get that?

Comment: @user17762 Don't you mean $m-1$?

Comment: @Trancot Nope, it is $\min(m,n)-1$. For instance, consider the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\ 2 & -2\\ 3 & -3\\ 4 & -4 \end{bmatrix}$$ Here $m=4$ and $n=2$. But rank is $n-1=1$.

Comment: @user17762, Oh, no, I mean the upper index on your sum, namely $\overset{\overset{?}{n-1}}{\sum}$.

Comment: @Trancot Oh yes. Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: For $m=2$, $n=1$, the rank is at most $\min(m, n) - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0$? Or do you mean $\min(m - 1, n)$?

Comment: @WolframH If $n=1$ and if the constraint the OP gives is satisfied then the matrix is a zero matrix and hence the rank is $0$.

Comment: @user17762 Sorry if I'm dumb, but I don't get it. At all. For $m=2$, $n=1$, doesn't $a_{11} = 1$, $a_{21} = -1$ fulfill the constraint? (Unlike the example you give in your comment above?)

Comment: -1 (if I could) I still think this is wrong, author fails to explain his conclusion.